# Jasmine 2.0 rc* waits is not defined

Tags: jasmine

Just upgraded to **jasmine 2.0 rc5** from **1.3** and now all my tests that used `waits()` are broken because the `waits()` and `waitsFor()` function are undefined. I can't seem to find any reference to that anywhere online, is anyone aware of what is the new API to replace wait() ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the usage syntax for asynchronous calls changed.
You can easily see the differences between the two versions in its documentations:

[Jasmine 1.3 Asynchronous support](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) uses `waitsFor()` and `run()` functions.

According to [Jasmine 2.0 Asynchronous support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support), these functions has been wiped out from the library. However, Jasmine 2.0 adds async support to the primitive `beforeEach()`, `afterEach()` and `it()` functions. The callback functions passed to these functions now can take an argument that indicates if the spec can or can't run.

Then, when you reach the necessary conditions to run your test (whenever your async job is complete), you simply call `done()`. And all the magic happens ;)

From the documentation:

```
describe("Asynchronous specs", function() {
    var value;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            value = 0;
            done();
        }, 1);
    });

    it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
        value++;
        expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        done();
    });
});
```

The `it()` spec above will run only after the `setTimeout()` call, because `done()` is called there. Note the `it()` callback takes an argument (`done`).

Comment: Neat, did not see that the 2.0 doc was up! Thanks for the pointer

Comment: I must say great answer!! Had random errors because of that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 5000

Please refer the below URL for Jasmine Documentation...
http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Section is "Asynchronous Support" in the documentation.