# Jasmine 2.0: refactoring out 1.3's runs() and waitsFor()

Tags: javascript, jasmine

The recently released Jasmine 2.0 removes the [waits functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119324/jasmine-2-0-rc-waits-is-not-defined) and the `runs()` from the Async Jasmine 1.3.

I have old 1.3 tests I'd like to transition to the new style.

For the waits, in most cases it seems like you can write `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` carefully for the same effect.

What is the best way to reproduce the `runs()` which simply executes the contained functions sequentially?

My first try:

```
runs(function() {
  expect(true).toBe(true);
}
```

becomes

```
(function() {
  expect(true).toBe(true);
})()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is possible to use a setTimeout in your it() block.

```
it("is asynchronous", function(done) {
  var isItDone = false;
  $.ajax('/some/url').success(function() { isItDone = true; });

  setTimeout(function(){
    expect(isItDone).toBeTrue();
    done(); // call this to finish off the it block
  }, 500);

});
```

However, I found that that slowed down my test suite dramatically so I created my own extension which recreates the polling functionality that waitsFor provided.

https://gist.github.com/abreckner/110e28897d42126a3bb9

Comment: Thank you very much, while it is possible to re-arrange this logic using a combination of beforeEach/afterEach and it functions as Gregg demonstrates above, this a very clean approach for a quick one-to-one conversion from Jasmine 1.3 to 2.0

Comment: This solution is still necessary for when you need to poll for a condition to exist (when the code you are testing doesn't provide a callback, but does operate asynchronously).

Comment: This is so lame. `waitFor` is really a happens-before edge, which the timer does not guarantee conceptually. It is a shame `waitFor` has been removed.

Answer (score 22):

In jasmine 1.3 and previous, the `runs` and `waits`/`waitsFor` should have only been necessary if you had some asynchronous code that you needed to wait until it was done before doing the next part of the test. In that case you would have something like:

```
it("is asynchronous", function() {
    var isItDone = false;
    runs(function() {
        $.ajax('/some/url').success(function() { isItDone = true; });
    });

    waitsFor(function() {
        return isItDone;
    });

    runs(function() {
        // this won't run until the waitsFor returns true
    });
});
```

Jasmine 2.0 moved to using a `done` callback for `beforeEach`, `it`, and `afterEach` if they do something asynchronous that you need to wait for.

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    $.ajax('/some/url').success(done);
});

it("is asynchronous", function() {
    // this won't run until the done callback is invoked from the beforeEach
});
```

Comment: Might the new it() format add more extraneous tests to the log than the old format did? The codebase's tests that I was working in was waiting for a lot of slow jquery-jasmine manipulations to the DOM.

Comment: If you needed to do two asynchronous things one after the other, you would need two `beforeEach` calls.

Comment: Alternatively, there's nothing to stop you from holding on to the `done` callback until you've completed a couple of asynchronous steps.

Comment: done() expects to be invoked via an ajax call, whereas waitsFor or runs would work for any arbitrary piece of code, so you can't refactor them out with done()

Comment: What if I don't want to make my async call before each unit test, and only in just one test?  The 'done()' mechanism doesn't provide feature parity with waits/runs.